# Why does the content in my div not remain the same when resizing window?

Tags: css

I have this page: http://bit.ly/1In9YCe

It looks as intended on big screens (desktop) but the issue is that when the window is resized down to small screen widths, the "Agree" and "Disagree" labels start to take up their own line instead of being nicely placed before and after the slider on the same line as the slider. I can't for the life of me figure out why they do this, since the available width should be sufficient. Will a kind soul please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in the CSS there is a display:block defined:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px)
.ui.form .choice-text {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

If you remove the **display:block** it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `width: 100%` rather than `width:500px` for example on the divs in column 1.

Comment: Thank you, Paddy! Pierrezzz pointed me to the source of my problem.